# Join operation on rdds with mutable objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a question，in case I have 2 pair RDDs:

```
RDD1 = RDD[(1,1), (1,2)]
RDD2 = RDD[(1, obj)]    // obj is an mutable scala object
```

`RDD1.join(RDD2)` operation should get: `RDD[(1, (1,obj1)), (1, (2,obj2))]`

the question is: are `obj1` and `obj2` references to the same object? If they are, what happened during this join process?

I used to think that they are two objects deserialized from `obj`'s serialization result, but today I found that operations on `obj1` could be reflected in `obj2`, and I suddenly got confused.

Thanks

Comment: **mutability** + **distributed computations** = _disaster_. - Any reason why `obj` has to be mutable?

Comment: May I ask how to create "RDD[(1,1), (1,2)]" with an actual code?

Comment: @mon just run `val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(List((1,1),(1,2)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can never know for sure if these will be same object or no. 
It depends on spark internal implementation.

If you need any kind of mutable stuff processed - you need to store objects outside (in hive, hdfs..) and only reference them by id during processing. Though it is not that simple, because the same object in that case might be accessed from multiple threads/executors and you need to handle that correctly.

Generally, as you've been told in comments - using mutable objects in distributed computation is very fragile thing that could be easily broken and hard to solve the problem later.